# Confusing Syntax Error (FROM statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, syntax-error

I am trying to update table 1's date column to a date in the future, otherwise known as decommissioned. I am getting a syntax error under the FROM statement. There is no other information that I am given other than

> INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR 'FROM'.

```
UPDATE [database1].[dbo].[table1]
SET [database1].[dbo].[table1].[datecolumn1] = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
WHERE [database1].[dbo].[table1].[END_DATE] > GETDATE() 
FROM [database1].[dbo].[table1] 
INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo].[table2] ON [database1].[dbo].[table1].[namecolumn1] = [database2].[dbo].[table2].[namecolumn2]
GO
```

Comment: Why do you want to store `'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'`? Seems like a real hack solution...

Comment: A quick glance at the [**official MSDN documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) would have easily revealed what's wrong with your statement ...

Comment: @marc_s I know I blanked /:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause should be after `FROM` :

```
UPDATE [database1].[dbo].[table1]
SET [database1].[dbo].[table1].[datecolumn1] = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
FROM [database1].[dbo].[table1] 
INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo].[table2] ON [database1].[dbo].[table1].[namecolumn1]=[database2].[dbo].[table2].[namecolumn2]
WHERE [database1].[dbo].[table1].[END_DATE] > GETDATE() 
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

The `where` clause should come last. Additionally, you have a typo in the word "innner" (should be "inner" - or better yet, just drop it completely):

```
UPDATE [database1].[dbo].[table1]
SET    [database1].[dbo].[table1].[datecolumn1] = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
FROM   [database1].[dbo].[table1] 
JOIN   [database2].[dbo].[table2] ON 
       [database1].[dbo].[table1].[namecolumn1] = 
       [database2].[dbo].[table2].[namecolumn2]
WHERE  [database1].[dbo].[table1].[END_DATE] > GETDATE()
```